# Fan running at max speed even at low temperaure

Tags: kernel, dell, fan, temperature

I'm using a Dell Latitude 7490 model and Ubuntu has been installed on it for a while but I have never faced this problem. The fan starts running automatically and at any time even when the laptop is in idle state and even when the CPU temperature is low. It starts around 7k rpm and then after some time the speed decreases but the fan is still going on.
[image]

I don't know the reason because I have never faced this issue before. Is this something related to BIOS but I haven't finger around with BIOS.

Comment: I guess a hardware problem. Fans exhaust blocked with dust ? Cooler not tight on surface ?

Comment: no the exhaust are clean and good as new.